# getBytes exceeds data length, but the range is obviously less than the length

Tags: objective-c

I am getting this output:

```
[NSConcreteData getBytes:range:]: range {2605022, 2605022} exceeds data length 3907534'
```

From this statement:

```
for(uint i = data.length*2/3; i<data.length; i++){
//        NSLog(@"i: %u",i);
        [data getBytes:buffer range:NSMakeRange(i,i)];
}
```

What I am doing wrong? I have never used Objective-C before, so I really don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4):

For those in my shoes, NSMakeRange is not start and end. It is start and length. A similar question was posed here: http://idevapps.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=181